# Can an app cause your iPhone to crash

Tags: iphone, ios, restart

I installed [Quick Notes with Widget](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/quick-notes-with-widget/id944786923) on my iPhone SE (1st gen, iOS 14.1) and after a while my phone kept restarting every 5 minutes. Removing the app solved this issue. So I was wondering if, even when not running an app could cause you phone to crash. Note that I put a widget from the app on my Home Screen.